# I was banned from the US for giving false information. For how long am I banned?

Tags: visas, usa, visa-bans

The US embassy in Mumbai banned me in 2015 for giving wrong information about my marriage. I want to know how many years I'm banned for. How can I know?

Comment: You could ask them, perhaps.  What exactly did they say to lead you to believe that you were banned?

Comment: You are banned forever. There are waivers available but those are very hard to come by. What kind of visa did you apply for?

Comment: @DanNeely [Marriage fraud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sham_marriage) which involves an actual albeit fraudulent marriage between a citizen and noncitizen is totally different from a non immigrant lying about his/her marital status on visa forms.

Comment: @TheZealot that is discussed in (a)(6)(c)(I) about halfway down.

Answer (score 45):

If you were banned for giving wrong information per your own words, then it is a ban for [misrepresentation or fraud](https://www.uscis.gov/policymanual/HTML/PolicyManual-Volume8-PartJ.html). It makes you [permanently inadmissible](https://www.uscis.gov/ilink/docView/SLB/HTML/SLB/0-0-0-1/0-0-0-29/0-0-0-2006.html) and you must apply for a [waiver](https://www.uscis.gov/policymanual/HTML/PolicyManual-Volume9-PartG.html) for the inadmissibility to be waived.

Waivers for fraud are very very difficult to get.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81272/discussion-on-answer-by-the-zealot-i-was-banned-from-the-us-for-giving-false-inf).